# JavaScript get original caller object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is a sample situation:

```
<smth onmouseover="test('hello')">
...
function test(pLabel)
{
    var sender = ?;
    var evt = ? || window.event;
}
```

In the function `test()` - how do I get the object that I hovered the mouse on and the mouse event? I've tried playing with the callee property but didn't get it to work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to define your event handlers in the HTML itself. Try this:

```
<div id="something">...</div>
```

...

```
document.getElementById('something').onmouseover = function() {
    // use `this` to reference the <div>
    alert(this.id); // alerts "something"
};
```

Comment: -1 because while this is good advice, it's not at all relevant nor helpful to the original question.